# How to let MySQL NOW() function return the user time

Tags: mysql, triggers, sqldatetime

I ran into a very tricky MySQL issue..
Our DB is using type `DateTime` for the `updated_at` column, and now is too late to change it back to `TimeStamp`. I'm thus trying to add a trigger to update this `updated_at` column on table changing. The following is what I did:

`CREATE TRIGGER foo_schema.bar_datetime_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON foo_schema.bar
FOR EACH ROW
set NEW.updated_at = NOW();`

The `NOW()` function here returns the DB time; however, what I actually want is to set the `udpated_at` as the user time (Meaning the time of the user who made changes to table `bar`). Is it possible to handle this in MySQL?

Comment: "set the udpated_at as the user time" - you mean... instead of grabbing the current date, use the date that was in the existing updated_at column (as a DateTime)?

Comment: @Peter - not really. I mean, instead of grabbing the date from the DB server, use the date from the API server who made changes on table ```bar``` through JDBC/Slick